# Java backend trying to run PhantomJS on AWS Linux

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, phantomjs

I've an issue I've been trying to fix for months and I can't find a solution. I'm trying to run PhantomJS from Java backend, to access a specific url, using a Quartz Job and then after creating the file sending it via email using javax.mail.

This works fine on my local machine and I even tested on a AWS Windows Server and it works. When I try to deploy to a AWS Linux Server I'm changing the command to a bash but even though the phantomjs exits with a success the file is never created. Here is an example of the command I'm using (I've replaced the actual values to make it simpler):

```
bash  -c "cd /usr/bin && phantomjs --web-security=false path_to_phantomjs_file/phantomreport.js 'some_url_in_here' PDF /tmp/filename"
```

The parameters I've are:
 - Path to phantomreport.js the phantomsjs file to be used
 - The url I want to access and take a screenshot of
 - The type of file I want to export to
 - The path to the location I want the file to be saved as well as the file name

Here is my phantomreport.js code:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var systemargs = system.args;


if (systemargs.length === 1) {
  phantom.exit(2);
} else {
    var url = systemargs[1];
    var type = systemargs[2];
    var filename = systemargs[3];

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

page.open(url, function(status) {
  if(status === "success"){
      waitFor(function() {
          return page.evaluate(function() {
              var el = document.getElementById("content");
              if(el.offsetParent !== null){
                 return true; 
              }
              return false;
          });
      }, function () {
        switch(type){
            case "PDF":
                // Saving diagram as PDF
                page.render(filename + '.pdf');
                break;
            case "PNG":
                // Saving diagram as PNG
                page.render(filename + '.png');
                break;
            case "JPEG":
                // Saving diagram to JPEG
                page.render(filename + '.jpeg');
                break;
            case "SVG":
                //Saving diagram to SVG
                fs.write(filename + ".svg", chart);
                break;
            case "CSV":
                //Saving diagram to CSV
                fs.write(filename + ".csv", chart);
                break;
            case "XLS":
                //Saving diagram to XLS
                fs.write(filename + ".xls", chart);
                break;
        }
        phantom.exit(1);
      });
  } else {
      console.log("Unable to access network");
      phantom.exit(2);
  }
});
}

/**
 * Wait until the test condition is true or a timeout occurs. Useful for waiting
 * on a server response or for a ui change (fadeIn, etc.) to occur.
 *
 * @param testFx javascript condition that evaluates to a boolean,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param onReady what to do when testFx condition is fulfilled,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param timeOutMillis the max amount of time to wait. If not specified, 3 sec is used.
 */

"use strict";
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 30000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s / Set to 30 secs
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(2);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
}
```

I've checked permissions, I've escaped slashes properly. Everything I can think of. When I run it directly on the terminal it works fine. Running from Java doesn't work as the file is never created.

I'd appreciate the help

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Not the same thing...

Comment: @Liam this question involves both Java and JavaScript. A Java program is attempting to execute PhantomJS to run some JavaScript code.

Comment: I ask because [this edit is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53766358/3)